# Imagemagick library of codeigniter is not working

Tags: imagemagick, codeigniter-3

Imagemagick library with codeigniter is not working, 
The same image manipulation operations are working perfect with GD2 library, but not showing any output nor any errors with Imagemagic, library. What is the problem and how do I solve it? Thanks in advance

Code to resize image:

```
$data['title'] ='Resize Image';
$upload['upload_path'] = './assets/images/';
$upload['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$this->load->library('upload',$upload);
$filedata1 = $this->upload->data();
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
    show_error($this->upload->display_errors());
}           
$this->load->library('image_lib');
//$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
$config['library_path'] = '/usr/X11R6/bin/';
$config['source_image'] = $this->upload->data('full_path');
$config['width']         ='100';
$config['height']       = 250;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
if(!$this->image_lib->resize()){
    show_error($this->image_lib->display_errors());
}
$filedata = $this->upload->data();
$data['img2'] = base_url().'/assets/images/'.$filedata['file_name'];
print $this->load->view('pages/result',$data,true);
```

Comment: try by replacing `imagemagick` with `ImageMagick`

Comment: Are you certain the imagemagick extension is loaded in you PHP setup?

Comment: @pradeep didn't work.

Comment: @DFriend no imagemagick extension is not loaded in php setup!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by loading the imagemagick extension in PHP setup and replacing 'ImageMagick' by imagick.